# Using a separate ExecutionContext for Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Play 2.5 with Slick. The [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlickAdvancedTopics#Connection-Pool) on this topic simply state that everything is managed by Slick and Play's Slick module. This example however, prints `Dispatcher[akka.actor.default-dispatcher]`:

```
class MyDbioImpl @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import profile.api._
  def selectSomeStuff(): Future[MyResult] = db.run {
    println(ec)
    [...]
  }
}
```

Since the execution context is printed inside db.run, it seems like all of my database access will also be executed on the default execution context.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780545/play-slick-with-securesocial-running-db-io-in-a-separate-thread-pool/19781063#19781063) to an older question which, at the time, solved the problem. But this solution is since deprecated, it is suggested to use dependency injection to acquire the application context. When I try to do this, I get an error saying that play.akka.actor.slick-context does not exist...

```
class MyDbioProvider @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                               protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
  extends Provider[MyDbioImpl] {
  override def get(): MyDbioImpl = {
    val ec = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("play.akka.actor.slick-context")
    new MyDbioImpl(dbConfigProvider)(ec)
  }
}
```

Edit:
Is Slick's execution context a "normal" execution context which is defined in a config file somewhere? Where does the context switch take place? I assumed the entry point to the "database world" is at `db.run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/database.html):

> Every Database contains an AsyncExecutor that manages the thread pool
>   for asynchronous execution of Database I/O Actions. Its size is the
>   main parameter to tune for the best performance of the Database
>   object. It should be set to the value that you would use for the size
>   of the connection pool in a traditional, blocking application (see
>   About Pool Sizing in the HikariCP documentation for further
>   information). When using Database.forConfig, the thread pool is
>   configured directly in the external configuration file together with
>   the connection parameters. If you use any other factory method to get
>   a Database, you can either use a default configuration or specify a
>   custom AsyncExecutor.

Basically it says you don't need to create an isolated ExecutionContext since Slick already isolates a thread pool internally. Any call you make to Slick is non-blocking thus you should use the default ExecutionContext.

Comment: So as long as I don't specify any settings to change the default config, Slick will use its own execution context. I wonder, where does the actual context change take place if not in db.run? And I should be able to see the configuration of this context at runtime, right?

Comment: I don't think I follow what you meant, @Paco1, but I'll try to answer you. When you say the "actual context change" do you mean the `ExecutionContext` used by Slick? Well, yes, roughly speaking it's created and used inside the `db.run` function. You should be able to see the configuration at runtime since Slick exposes the [`Database` object via JMX](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/config.html). But also you could just check what the default configuration that Slick uses or even override it yourself (increase thread number, queue size, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's exactly what I was asking. The docs say that, given a database named "default", Slick will create a thread pool with that name to run its IO in it. So I went ahead and created some more in-memory DBs, orders and customers, but no corresponding config shows up during runtime. Furthermore, when I inject an ActorSystem somewhere and access it's dispatchers there are no additional dispatchers beyond the default-dispatcher from Play. Does Slick register the ExecCtx there, or does it hide them? Or do I understand something completely wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think Slick adds a new dispatcher to Akka, it just create a new `ExecutionContext` inside its own context and hide it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Slick's implementation of this can be seen in the BasicBackend.scala file: the runInContextSafe method. The code is as follows:

```scala
val promise = Promise[R]
val runnable = new Runnable {
   override def run() = {
      try {
         promise.completeWith(runInContextInline(a, ctx, streaming, topLevel, stackLevel = 1))
      } catch {
              case NonFatal(ex) => promise.failure(ex)
      }
   }
}
DBIO.sameThreadExecutionContext.execute(runnable)
promise.future
```

As shown above, Promise is used here, and then its code is executed quickly using its internal thread pool, and the Future object of the Promise is returned. Therefore, when Await.result/ready is executed, the Promise here is probably already executed by Slick's internal thread, so it is enough to get the result, and it is possible to execute Await.result/ready in an environment such as Play. Of non-blocking.

For details, please refer to Scala's documentation on Future and Promise: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html